# Minor alignment issue in few of the Badge page's "Awarded to" text

Tags: bug, design, badges

There is an minor alignment issue in the few of the badges section. For an example: [Marshal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/160/marshal), [Curious](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/242/curious) badges in MSE

For few of the entries the text **to** is displaying in the next line. This is not a major issue, but for uninformative this should be fix.

<del>After inspect the element, CSS class `single-badge-awarded`'s `width: 48%`. To increase the class `width: 50%` will solve the issue.</del>

Marshal badge current page screenshot for reference:

[image: Awarded to - alignment issue]

Comment: Sounds like yet another "but it fits perfectly on *my* browser" issue. I'm starting to think we should have a tag for these. Maybe [meta-tag:font-metrics]?