# Don't split sentence about badge awarding

Tags: feature-request, bug, badges, localization, russian-stackoverflow

Some badge help pages contain sentence "Awarded {time} to", e.g. [delete-tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/87):

> [image: awarded to]

As far as I see in Transifex the mentioned sentence is separated to two pieces:

- [Awarded $relativeTime$](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40263970?key=d091724c55f9753876af63441079d93b)
- [to](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40263959?key=2177f4fdd144e4a6fe0e71858190672c)

Is it possible to use the whole string in this case? Moreover, it already [exists](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40263969?key=c57c9bdcab1db23336ae5ce2f042f34b), but seems used anywhere else. Using one single string is necessary for better translation.

Related question on ruSO: [Формулировка о присвоении знака](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3934/176217)

Comment: Related [_Minor alignment issue in few of the Badge page's “Awarded to” text_](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290496/312043)

Comment: @Arulkumar yep, ugly one.